# How can I calculate an outer function in python?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a random function like func(x,y) = cos(x) + sen(y) + x*y how can I apply it to all the pairs of elements in 2 arrays?

I found https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html and
discovered that there are outer functions for all the basic operations. But what if I want to do it with a custom function?

Imagine array1 is [1,2], array2 is [3,4] and the function I wanted to apply is called f(float, float)

The expected output would be

[f(1,3) f(1,4)

f(2,3) f(2,4)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you make sure to write your function in such a way that it broadcasts properly, you can do

```
func(x_arr[:, None], y_arr)
```

to apply it to all pairs of elements in two 1-dimensional arrays `x_arr` and `y_arr`.

For example, to write your example function in a way that broadcasts, you'd write it as

```
def func(x, y):
    return np.cos(x) + np.sin(y) + x*y
```

since `np.cos`, `np.sin`, `+`, and `*` broadcast and vectorize across arrays.

---

As for if it doesn't broadcast? Well, some might suggest `np.vectorize`, but that has a lot of tricky things you have to keep in mind, like maintaining a consistent output `dtype` and not having side effects. If your function doesn't broadcast, I'd recommend just using list comprehensions:

```
np.array([[func(xval, yval) for yval in y_arr] for xval in x_arr])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
    x, y = np.asarray(x)[:, None], np.asarray(y)
    return np.cos(x) + np.sin(y) + x*y
```

The `[:, None]` adds another dimension to an array and therefor triggers [NumPys broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
>>> func([1,2], [3,4])
array([[ 3.68142231,  3.78349981],
       [ 5.72497317,  6.82705067]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a nested loop. Using a single element in one array, iterate through all the elements in the other array, then proceed to the next element in the first array and repeat.

This would be simple if you just want to print the result, if you want to store the results into another array, this would still work, it just uses a lot of resources.